# What is the correct way to use PHP date/time with the jquery timeago plugin?

Tags: php, jquery, datetime, time, timeago

I'm using the yarp timeago plugin with Chicago CDT time on my server. THe problem i'm having is that it is showing different "ago" times on different PCs and in different timezones.

The PHP code im using to generate the UTC time is

```
 $dateutc = gmdate('l F dS Y H:i',strtotime(''.$date.''));
```

Where $date is the timestamp of an item from the system in CDT (Chicago) time such as 2014-06-15 04:16:33, and $dateutc is supposed to be the UTC time.

The HTML to render the plugin output is

```
 <abbr class=\"timeago\" title=\"$dateutc\"></abbr>
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to generate the UTC time in PHP?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just as simple as the format. Use this instead:

```
$dateutc = gmdate(DATE_ISO8601, strtotime(''.$date.''));
```

Comment: I've tried this. It gives different ago values when viewed in different countries.